# Laravel get posts have atleast one tag on each category of tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to list all posts have at least one tag on each category i selected.
In our laravel app we have a Post and Tag model.

In Post model we have:

```php
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tags', 'post_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

What is query to select post have atleast one of {3,2} tags and atleast one of {8,10} ?

I write this code:

```php
$tags = ['news' => [3,2], 'alert' => [8,10]];

Post::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tags){
   foreach($tags as $category => $tag){
      $query->whereIn('tags.id', $tag);
   }
}
```

posts

```
+---------+---------------+
|    id   |     title     |
+---------+---------------+
|    1    |   post 1...   |
|    2    |   post 2...   |
|    3    |   post 3...   |
|    4    |   post 4...   |
|    5    |   post 5...   |
|    6    |   post 6...   |
|    7    |   post 7...   |
|    8    |   post 8...   |
|    9    |   post 9...   |
+---------+---------------+
```

tags

```
+---------+-------+------------+
|    id   |  name |  category  |
+---------+-------+------------+
|    1    | stock |   news     |
|    2    |  acc  |   news     |
|    3    |  etc  |   news     |
|    4    |  eco  |   news     |
|    5    |  side |   ads      |
|    6    |  head |   ads      |
|    7    | footer|   ads      |
|    8    |  info |   alert    |
|    9    | danger|   alert    |
|   10    |success|   alert    |
+---------+-------+------------+
```

post_tags

```
+-----------+---------+
|  post_is  | tag_id  |
+-----------+---------+
|     1     |    3    |
|     1     |    4    |
|     1     |    5    |
|     1     |    8    |
|     1     |    9    |
|     1     |   10    |
|     9     |    9    |
|     9     |    6    |
|     3     |    7    |
|     7     |    1    |
|     7     |    2    |
|     7     |    8    |
+-----------+---------+
```

But result is nothing.

I need result as Post Eloquent and query performance is important.

larave version is 5.8.35

Comment: Your code looks good. Can you check the raw query generated.

Comment: Have you write get() in query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start here with a raw MySQL query which gets the job done.  Then, build your Laravel script around that.

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.title
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_tags pt
    ON pt.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY
    p.id,
    p.title
HAVING
    SUM(pt.tag_id IN (2, 3)) > 0 AND
    SUM(pt.tag_id IN (8, 10)) > 0;
```

Your Laravel code:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts p')
    ->join('post_tags pt', 'pt.post_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->groupBy('p.id', 'p.name')
    ->havingRaw('SUM(pt.tag_id IN (2, 3)) > 0 AND SUM(pt.tag_id IN (8, 10)) > 0')
    ->select('p.id', 'p.name')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but not working because of ```incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by```

Comment: Something isn't right here, because my query should be compatible with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.  Are you certain that you are actually running my code, completely unmodified?

Comment: No, your code not working so i just apply some change for working it. 
your code error is : ```SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'temp.posts p' doesn't exist...```
@tim-biegeleisen

Comment: I don't know your exact table names, I only know the information you have shared in your question.  Based on that information, my answer is valid.

Comment: My table name is exact same as your code but i don't know what is problem.

Comment: Well the error message is referring to `temp.posts`.  Is `temp` the name of your database?  If not, then whence is this error?

Comment: Yes, temp is my database.

Comment: From MySQL Workbench, type: `USE temp; SELECT * FROM posts` ... does this run without error?

Comment: there is no error, your raw query is completely answerd my problem. but your laravel code has error.

Comment: Can you change your laravel code base on Post model not raw Db ?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, this is up to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201724/discussion-between-mohammad-and-tim-biegeleisen).